# Python: time conversion

Tags: python, datetime, pytz, python-dateutil

I have been banging my head against Google and SO and not getting anywhere, but I am sure it has been answered a hundred times and is just buried.

I am receiving a time from a soap service and need to convert it to the time specified in the timezone offset, so

2014-02-06 13:30:00-05:00

should be

2014-02-06 08:30:00

so I can format and display the correct time for the event.

I have been playing with dateutil and pytz to no avail.  Can anyone point me to where I should be looking?  Everything I have found changes the timezone info, but it won't change the hour to where it belongs.

Comment: `from dateutil import parser`, `parser.parse('2014-02-06 13:30:00-05:00')` works out of the box. What step are you missing from there?

Comment: that works fine, but what I can't figure out is how to get the hour to change.  the datetime object dateutil returns still gives me 13, not 8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dateutil` handles the format straight out of the box:

```
from dateutil import parser

dt = parser.parse('2014-02-06 13:30:00-05:00')
```

Now you have a timezone-aware `datetime.datetime()` value, including displaying it as a UTC ISO8601 timestamp:

```
from dateutil import tz

print dt.astimezone(tz.tzutc()).isoformat(' ')
```

This uses [`datetime.datetime.astimezone()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone) to transform the timezone-aware `datetime` value to the UTC timezone.

Demo:

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> from dateutil import tz
>>> dt = parser.parse('2014-02-06 13:30:00-05:00')
>>> print dt.astimezone(tz.tzutc()).isoformat(' ')
2014-02-06 18:30:00+00:00
```

This includes a timezone offset (of `+00:00`), you can use the [`datetime.datetime.strftime()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) to format the string differently if desired.